# Attribute/element co-occurrence constraint in XML Schema

Tags: xml, schema, xsd

Is it possible to create an XML Schema which imposes a co-occurrence constraint to an attribute/element pair?

```
<primitive-list>
    <primitive name="P1">
        <definition><!-- primitive specification --></definition>
    </primitive>
    <primitive name="P2">
        <definition><!-- primitive specification --></definition>
    </primitive>

    <!-- other common primitives are specified here-->

<primitive-list>

<composite-list>
    <composite name="C1">
        <primitive ref="P1" />
        <primitive ref="P2" />
        <primitive>
            <definition><!-- inline primitive specification --></definition>
        </primitive>        
    </composite>

    <!-- Other compisites are specified here-->

</composite-list>
```

The schema should imply that:

- If a **primitive** element is specified inside a **primitive-list** element, then it should contain the **name** attribute and the embedded **definition** element, but not the **ref** attribute.
- If a **primitive** element is specified in the **composite** element, then it should contain either the **ref** attribute or the **definition** element. The **name** is allowed in neither cases.

I am pretty sure that it is possible since the **element** element in XML Schema itself behaves just like that. So anybody who is in possession of that sacred knowledge please share :-)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After searching on the Internet and digging in some books I figured out how to implement that.

First of all we need to define a generic type which accommodates all attributes and elements from both kinds of the **primitive** element. It is assumed that the **definition** element is defined somewhere else.

```
<xs:complexType name="primitive" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="definition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:Name" />
    <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:Name" />
</xs:complexType>
```

Then we define two **primitive** subtypes to be used in the **primitive-list** and
**composite** respectively.

```
<xs:complexType name="public-primitive">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="primitive">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="definition" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:Name" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="ref" use="prohibited" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="private-primitive">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="primitive">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="definition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" use="prohibited" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now we can define the **primitive-list** and **composite** elements in terms of these complex types as follows:

```
<xs:element name="primitive-list">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="primitive" type="public-primitive" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="composite">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="primitive" type="private-primitive" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:key name="definition-ref--co-occurrence--constraint">
                    <xs:selector xpath="." />
                    <xs:field xpath="definition|@ref" />
                </xs:key>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Let's take a look at the original schema requirements and see how they are enforced:

> - If a **primitive** element is specified inside a **primitive-list** element, then it should contain the **name** attribute and the embedded **definition** element, but not the **ref** attribute.

This requirement is enforced by the definition of the **public-primitive** type alone.

> - If a **primitive** element is specified in the **composite** element, then it should contain either the **ref** attribute or the **definition** element. The **name** is allowed in neither cases.

This requirement is enforced by the definition of the **private-primitive** type and by the **xs:key** element specified in the **primitive** element defined inside of the **composite** element. The **xs:key** guaranties that either **ref** or **definition** is present but not both.

Comment: This is really helpful. It's a shame that the xs:key restriction is attached to the element and not to a type, since that means you can't re-use it for other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  When creating your XML Schema, you will be creating a complex type for each scenario, based on where in the XML tree the element is defined.

If I get a moment later on i can try to actually get an example out here for you, I just don't have the time to get it all formatted perfectly for posting here.

I personally highly recommend looking at this [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_howto.asp), as it should get you what you need.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to create a complex type which allows either <b>ref</b> attribute or <b>definition</b> element, but not both of them?

Comment: I have to dig up a few references here to get the syntax 100% correct.  The key is that you are going to need to create named types to handle this, if I recall correctly.  I'll try to post up a full solution yet tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a sample, this gets you close, the only thing not handled is the primitive and ref attribute on the composite.  Looking at what I can find, it does almost seem to be impossible to do this via a schema.  I'm not 100% sure though, but in all cases where I have seen this done, a schema like this is used for high level validation and process code is then used to validate the individual items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.iowacomputergurus.com/stackoverflow/samples/xsdexample"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://www.iowacomputergurus.com/stackoverflow/samples/xsdexample"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>

  <xs:complexType name="PrimitiveType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="definition" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name ="name" use="required" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="primitive-list" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="primitive" type="PrimitiveType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="composite-list" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="composite">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="primitive" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="definition" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                          </xs:sequence>
                          <xs:attribute name="ref" use="optional" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>  
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort Mitchel, but the key point of the question was how to set a co-occurrence constraint to the ref/primitive pair. Apparently my bad English failed me in expressing that. So I corrected the question accordingly.

Comment: Dang!  You got the one last piece that I was working on, and since I wasn't sure of your problem area, I stopped working at it.  Great solution!