# XML Schema for attribute or subnode

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, xml-validation

Here is my problem. In a node, I wish to have either an attribute or a subnode (from a group). For instance:

```
<set_variable name="bob" value="3/>
```

or

```
<set_variable name="bob">
    <.../>
</set_variable>
```

The only way I found to do it is:

```
<xs:element name="set_variable" type="setVariableType"/>

<xs:complexType name="setVariableType">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:group ref="arithmeticGroup"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:integer" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:group name="arithmeticGroup">
    ....
</xs:group>
```

The problem with that solution is that it allows two forbidden ways:

```
<set_variable name="bob"/> <!-- Should at least have an attribute or a subnode -->
```

and

```
<set_variable name="bob" value="18"> <!-- Should not have both attribute and a subnode -->
    <.../>
</set_variable>
```

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with XSD 1.0; you either have to use Schematron assertions on top of XSD 1.0, or rely on XSD 1.1 [assertions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions) or [type alternatives](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative)  (just forged as a W3C rec on April 5th) and a compliant processor (none free, very few available).

Comment: Hi Petru, I was looking for this too.  Could you point me to where in the XSD 1.1 spec this is made possible (i.e. a choice between an element and an attribute)?  (Or, perhaps, online discussions of the working group, where they talk about it?)  I'd also like to see where in the old XSD 1.0 spec it isn't possible - but I think there's unlikely to be just one place to point at!  Also, just BTW, do you think the XSD 1.1 is likely to get widely adopted?  Many thanks for any answers you can give!

Comment: @13ren, I've updated the answer with the link to XSD 1.1 assertions. The fact that is not possible to achieve what was requested with XSD 1.0 has to do with how content models can be defined in 1.0. There is no concept of a choice of content model which involves attributes (choice only handles particles). XSD 1.1 now supports it - see [Type Alternatives](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative). As to how widely adopted will be, it all depends how fast major players are going to move into. Microsoft is not showing any effort in this space...

Comment: (cont'd)... XSD2Code binding technologies have barely managed in some cases to support core XSD 1.0; and let's not even talk about enterprise modeling tools which are not specialized in XSD editing, yet are used widely for tasks related to XSD - and enterprise use is driving a lot of this. Personally I don't think XSD 1.1 will enjoy a comparable success with 1.0 simply because of timing; when 1.0 came, there was **kind of** nothing around - tooling and frameworks. Now there's so many of them, that the lowest common denominator will prevail for a while... I hope to be proven wrong..

Comment: @PetruGardea Thanks!  I looked at assertions and type alternatives - very complicated.  DTDs were already established when XSD came out (with a nicer syntax IMHO too) - but XSD addressed needs unmet by DTDs.  So I guess it depends on whether XSD 1.1 meets important needs or not - whether there is a "gap".  BTW: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/336494/50979) (the bottom part) suggesting using a key selector like `<xs:field xpath="definition|@ref"/>`, I think based on the idea that it must evaluate to *exactly one* node - but it didn't work when I tested it with `xmllint`.

Comment: @13ren, DTD wasn't that hard to replace. In my opinion, evolving from DTD to XSD was necessary on so many levels, and it brought in so many advantages, starting with the fact that XML syntax was used instead. I could relay from my own experience that many improvements in XSD 1.1 were met with resistence in my consulting practice; one particular topic was the use of assertions which, while now is so much powerful, it worries people with BRMS background that we'll be opening the gates to go back to writing business rules everywhere... Before with XSD 1.0 there wasn't much to be worried about...

Comment: @PetruGardea So, *too* powerful.  Can't win with that one.  I've been recently thinking that although the Java type system is not very expressive, it can be tedious to make something precisely correct, and there's diminishing returns.  And often, the power it does have is not used, so types are over-broad.  I'm not saying Java has the balance just right, but that there probably *is* a balance.  For XSD 1.1 assertions, although one could have a convention to not use them for business rules, if they *can* be used for it, I guess they will be.  What's the best way to handle their concerns?

Comment: (cont'd) @13ren; unfortunately, the answer you linked is not going to work in your case. While it is a nice attempt (he misses on exactly the most important part, the nature of the `definition` element), the problem with it has to do with the fact that a xs:field is different than an xs:selector; the former must resolve to some non-empty text. It only works when the (`definition`) element is of simple type or has simple content. So speaking to your scenario (arithmeticGroup), it won't work.

Comment: BTW: What advantage have you seen of XML syntax in practice?  Obviously, it's eating your own dog food, and some benefits with parsing tools and XSLT for transforming schema etc - but I don't think they are actually used very much in practice.  e.g. few people write schema-processing tools. I find XML syntax not very readable for programming language-like tasks, and this effect occurs all the time.  I think many people are insulated from the syntax with various tools.

Comment: @PetruGardea Thanks for the explanation - makes sense a key needs to have a string value.

Comment: @13ren, I could be called biased here, since XML Schema processing tools is a lot of what I do; still, I have seen more than a fair share of people trying to refactor XSDs and in my opinion, exactly because of accessibility in parsing XML. I agree with XML not being good for a programming language, if not only because of its verbosiness. Yet, when it comes to presentation, the wide-"world" is based on XML (HTML isn't quite, but it's cleaning its act)...

Comment: @PetruGardea How is wanting to refactor a XSD because of parsing XML?  Do your clients do that?  Refactoring in general (e.g. of Java source code) is for things like clarity and ease of reuse.  I think if you work in XSD processing, the advantages of an XML syntax are prominent - otherwise you'd have to write/obtain a parser for the specific syntax. It can be done (e.g. Java, Python, Ruby etc have their own syntax and parsers - Java even has ANTLR), but it's extra step. Hmmmmm... that is a real benefit. Anyway, thanks very much for your answers!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16604/discussion-between-petru-gardea-and-13ren)